# Saving a relation on the current user

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

Getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'success' of undefined` when trying to `Parse.User.current().save()` once a Relation has been set. It's complaining - any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

```
1 flagRead: function() {
2   // Mark as READ
3   var user = Parse.User.current();
4   var relation = user.relation("read");
5   relation.add(this.model);
6   user.save();
7   console.log("Marked as read");
8 },
```

Comment: Heads up. While setting the relation on `this.model` instead of doing it on `Parse.User.current()` it seems that `var relation = this.model.relation("read"); relation.add(Parse.User.current());` does not require `this.model.save();` to make it into Mongo. It works as a charm but we need to understand why `.save()` is not mandatory. Any clarification would help! Thanks :)

Comment: `.save()` in fact creates a duplicate.